# API for ACM initialization when creating a Custom Domain Name in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-acm

I'm creating an API Gateway with an associated Custom Domain Name using Boto3.

When adding a Custom Domain Name, there's a period of about 40 minutes where the ACM Certificate is "initializing". See below screenshot to see what I'm referring to. I'm unable to find any reference in the Boto3 API of how I can programmatically wait for that initialization to complete.

The [`create_domain_name()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_domain_name) API call has a field in the response known as `domainNameStatus` which returns `AVAILABLE` even while the ACM is still being initialized.

Have you or anyone you know heard of a programmatic way or other approach to wait for the initialization of the ACM certificate to complete?

[image: ACM Initialization]

Comment: Tried using an ACM waiter, but that did not wait on what was being initialized. Instead it returns successfully right away.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/acm.html#waiters